# Code behaving different on phones and tablets

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've built a page that writes and reads info to and from a Firebase database. Now, this works well and all on my PC, and when simulating different phones and laptops in the inspector. The thing is that on an actual android or iOS the references seems to be off. It still saves to the database but in the wrong places. What am I missing?

Here's the line that sets values in the database:

```
    database.ref("birds/birdList/" + [newId] + "/seenE").set(checkValue);
```

And on iPhone, for example, this line sets in: birds/birdList as "seenE: true" or "seenE: false" dependning on the user's input.

I'm thinking that it might have something to do with **var newId**, that on touchscreens the clicking doesn't get the id passed on as it should, but don't know how to track that on an actual phone (in the inspector I can log the activity, but as I said it works simulated as an phone on my computer anyway).

```
function getId() {
var _id = document.activeElement.id;
newId = _id.substring(8);
```

}

I use **click Event** to trigger my functions. Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try touchstart/touchend event for mobile devices instead of the click?

You can catch the eventType and attach that to your actual event:

```
// Use touchstart if available, fallback to click
var clickEventType = document.ontouchstart !== null ? 'touchstart' : 'click';
```

And use `clickEventType` on your event. This seems to do the trick for me usually.